# How to call Jquery function once ajax complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax content for website, I like to call this resize function whenever ajax request complete. I tried something but not working. Please help me on this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#fullHeightDiv').css('min-height', window.innerHeight+'px');
    }).resize();
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I see in your initial code example and based on what you've written I *think* this will do everything you're hoping to do.

```
function setMinHeight() {
  $('#fullHeightDiv').css('min-height', window.innerHeight+'px');
}

$(document)
  .ajaxComplete(function() {
    // Call function after every ajax call on the page
    setMinHeight();
  })
  .ready(function() {

    // Call function after every resize event.
    $(window).resize(setMinHeight);

    // Call function once DOM is ready.
    setMinHeight();
  });
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? do you see errors in the browser console?